# AJAX request is never sent. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

```
var data;

$(document).ready(function(){
var rows = document.getElementById("orderlist_1").rows; var cell = rows[rows.length - 1].cells[3];
data = "id="+cell.innerHTML
checkAndNotify();
})

function checkAndNotify()
{   
    alert("oo");
    $("#shownoti").load("/mostrecenttransaction","id=2008010661301520679");
    t = setTimeout("checkAndNotify()",3000)
    return true;
}

//$(document).ready(checkAndNotify())
```

In the above code, window with content is shown every 3 seconds when I open the webpage.
But, the next line is as if its never executes. If I manually open the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/mostrecenttransaction/?id=2008010661301520679 , it returns me a HttpResponse so why is the AJAX call never sent.

I have checked using Inspect Element of google chrome by going to the network tab & observed that even if alert("oo") is executes every 3 seconds, but ajax request is never sent. Can anyone help me out. I have spent so much time on but I am unable to figure it out. You can check the code simply by git clone & "git checkout counternoti". **Code can be run simply by "python2 manage.py runserver", no configuration needed.(enter username as "123456789" and password as abcd** It would be nice if if you could see it for yourself. At least, it damn interesting to me as a beginner.

> My repo ->
>   https://github.com/shadyabhi/pycourt_login/tree/counternoti

Related code in urls.py:(./urls.py)

```
(r'^mostrecenttransaction/',mostRecentTransaction),
```

views.py: (./views.py:line 339)

```
def mostRecentTransaction(request):
    transactid_atdocument = request.GET['id'][7:]
    latestid = Ordersss.objects.latest('transaction_id').transaction_id[7:]
    print latestid, transactid_atdocument
    if latestid > transactid_atdocument:
        return HttpResponse("Food List outdated, please refresh")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("")
```

templates: (./templates/home.html:line 282)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pycourt/newordernotification.js"></script>
..
..
<div id=shownoti"></div>
```

I am new to jQuery & AJAX and this thing has driven me crazy after I tried it for hours solving it. **Main point is, if the "alert" is shown then why not the AJAX request?** A reply would be highly appreciated.

Comment: the request is likely being cached because you aren't changing any parameters.

Comment: Its definitely not cached. I have checked it by clearing the cache.

Comment: Ok, well another thing I see is that `<div id=shownoti"></div>` should be `<div id="shownoti"></div>`.  If `$()` selector does not find the div, it won't load.  Maybe this is just a copy/paste error though.

Comment: Hmm. I wasnt looking at it bcos I was trying to look AJAX request in Firebug. Anyways, corrected that. THanks. Now, I used rob.alarcon's answer. After that this AJAX request is sent only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "mostRecentTransaction",
    type: "GET",
    data: { id : 2008010661301520679 },
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
        jQuery('#shownoti').html(data).hide().fadeIn(1500);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also add in `cache: false` for this to make sure jquery explicitly doesn't cache anything in the request.

Comment: OK. Done. Moved the checkAndNotify() function outside $(document).ready() at the top and used your way to do AJAX request. Now, everything is fine. BUT, I really want to know what went wrong in my code. Why this executes, but not mine ($("#shownoti").load).

Comment: If anyone tells me that why the way I called didnt work, but the way he suggested works, I will be a happy man. Anyone?

Comment: because you're not doing an ajax call actually, you're missing parameters in your load call -- check this link api.jquery.com/load heres an example that ilustrate this: $('#result').load('ajax/test.html', function() { alert('Load was performed.'); }); // the closure after the data (ajax/test.html in this example) its the necesary callback

Comment: Thanks. thank you very much for your answer. I had been scratching my since so long. I thought it was optional as its in [].

Comment: Just if someone sees it, ajax call is actually 'url: "/mostrecenttransaction",'

Answer (score 0):

Try using setInterval instead of setTimeout

Comment: That's not invalid JavaScript.  He's not using an enclosure and he's not adding a method to an object with prototype so it doesn't matter in what order his declaration of checkAndNotify() comes and it should be outside $(document).ready

Comment: How did you check that error? There was no error shown in Chrome;s Inspect Element. btw, I moved that but still no success

Comment: jsLINT is a javascript validation tool that runs on the command line. I always run it when developin in JS and if I have a tough bug.

Comment: @shadyabhi, jsLINT was built by Douglas Crockford. It can be found here http://www.jslint.com/ both the on line version and the downloadable command line version can be found there.   jsLINT does not necessarily report "errors", (although it can catch a lot) it is primarily for adhering to Douglas's version of "best practices" for java script.  The point is, just because you don't adhere to every rule that Douglas created, it does not mean you are doing it wrong, nor is your code "invalid javascript".  It just helps you to avoid common tricky pitfalls of the JavaScript language.

Comment: in addition personally I don't agree with every rule in jsLINT, admittedly though there are a few core rules that are *very* good to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am new to all these stuff so I didnt new about it.

Comment: It works with setTimeout() as rob .alarcon told. But, why his AJAX request is sent but not the way I sent it.